# Does air speed vary in a jet engine axial flow compressor?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Does it get slower and slower after each stage because of the pressure increase? Or does the shrinking of the space after each stage compensate for this and the air speed at the last stage of the compressor is the same as at the first stage?

Comment: hi just a quick suggestion, put up a graphic of the engine design.  I say this because in your post you say _Does it get slower and slower after each stage because of the pressure increase_....to me, any pressure increase implies flow velocity increase through the engine. Unless I see the directions you are talking about, I could not give a proper answer... thanks and regards

Comment: also in your post you ask is _the air speed at the last stage of the compressor is the same as at the first stage?_  the idea of any jet engine is to get a **much** faster flow at the far end than at the front of the engine, so my guess this is not want you want, but a diagram would help clear up any misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 1):

The increase in pressure through the compressor stages is roughly compensated for by the decrease in cross section, so the velocity is roughly constant as you suggest.  That's the most efficient situation.  But it doesn't have to be exact for the engine to work, and it varies for a given engine depending on where you are in the flight regime.  For example, it may be different when the plane is sitting on the runway that it is at cruise speed and altitude.  And of course, the velocity is greatly reduced once the flow gets to the combustion chamber--otherwise the flame would go out.

Comment: And all this gets more complex for supersonic flight where conventionally the supersonic airflow is slowed to subsonic upon entry into the engine and this creates significant compression itself. Hence the search for a practical supersonic combustion jet engine.

Answer (score 0):

The stages of a compressor consisting of rotor and stator form small diffusers for the air flow which lowers the speed and increases the pressure, as it is intended. The higher the pressure the better, and also the lower the velocity the better for the efficient mixing with the fuel in combustion chamber as very high velocities do now cause very efficient mixing.

Comment: "**The higher the pressure the better, and also the lower the pressure the better** for the efficient mixing with the fuel in combustion chamber as very high velocities do now cause very efficient mixing."  So is higher pressure or lower pressure better?

Comment: sorry JMac, I fixed it, the higher the pressure and the lower the velocity, of course there are limits for both.